# Loop logic (Java)

Tags: java, loops

This may seem silly, but I'm a bit confused about the following code:

```
public class Loops{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 2;
    int k = 0;
    boolean continue = i<j;
    while (continue && k < 2) {
        i++;
        j--;
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
}

}
```

This program prints 0, but I just don't understand why it doesn't print 1.  The way I see it, after one loop `i = j = 1`.  And thus continue = false.  So if anyone can explain to me the logic behind this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: continue is never been updated in the loop, are you sure?

Comment: That code does not compile, as `continue` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: take care while using continue, it's a java keyword used in loops, like break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

continue does not reevaluate itself after every loop iteration because he is defined outside of the loop.
instead, check in the loop condition for i < j

```
    while (i<j && k < 2) {
        i++;
        j--;
        k++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop would be optimized by compiler as:

```
boolean continue = i<j;
while (true && k < 2)
```

and finally

```
while (k < 2)
```

So it need to loop two times to exit

```
After the first loop: j == 1, k == 1 
After the second loop: j == 0, k == 2, exit now
```

this is why finally `j == 0`

Try out putting condition inside a `while()`:

```
while (i<j && k < 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Continue is only set outside of loop body, it is never updated during the loop. Thus `continue` is set to true before the loop starts and then never modified again.

Answer (score 0):

You only set the value of variable 'k' once and consequently continue as well.  You need to re-evaluate the conditional expression inside the loop as well.

That said, I would suggest you refrain from using 'continue' as a varible name; I'm fairly certain it is a reserved word in many languages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `continue` variable always evaluates to `true` (0 < 2) so we can ignore it.

First iteration:

- `i` ends up evaluating to 1.
- `j` ends up evaluating to 1.
- `k` ends up evaluating to 1.
- As `k < 2`, we do another iteration.

Second iteration:

- `i` ends up evaluating to 2.
- `j` ends up evaluating to 0.
- `k` ends up evaluating to 2.
- As `k == 2`, we exit the loop.

Then we print j, which evaluates to 0.